# Skip tr selection using jquery on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So, I have this situation right now:

https://jsfiddle.net/rucjr5cm/

```js
$(function() {
  var row = $('.DataList tbody tr.highlight');
  var index = row.index();
  console.log('current row: ' + index);

  function highlight(tableIndex) {
    $('.DataList tbody tr').removeClass('highlight');
    $('.DataList tbody tr:eq(' + tableIndex + ')').addClass('highlight');
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var currentRow = $('.DataList tbody tr.highlight');

    switch (e.which) {
      case 38:
        var prevRow = currentRow.closest('.DataList tbody tr:not(.Header, .SubHeader, .Total)').prev('tr');
        highlight(prevRow.index());
        break;
      case 40:
        var nextRow = currentRow.closest('.DataList tbody tr:not(.Header, .SubHeader, .Total)').next('tr');
        highlight(nextRow.index());
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
.Header,
.SubHeader,
.Total {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="data" class="DataList" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Header">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SubHeader">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Total">
      <td>6</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like for the highlighted row to skip the grey ones (which are defined by classes and cannot be modified). It would be nice also, if reached the last not greyed out one, to go to the first one (again, not greyed out).

I've tried using the closest + next and prev approach from jQuery too but got nothing out of it either.

I've never used the closest and next / prev approach and I'm certainly doing something wrong, could someone provide any help with it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: you function `highlight(tableIndex)` will always call by passing value -1 i.e `highlight(-1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make use of the [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`prevAll`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) functions:

```js
var rows = $('.DataList tbody tr');   // cache this for better performance

function highlight(row) {
  // changed to use the cached object
  rows.removeClass('highlight');
  
  // instead of using the index, you can just pass the object in
  row.addClass('highlight');
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  
  var currentRow = rows.filter('.highlight');   // use filter to get the current highlight

  switch (e.which) {
    case 38:
      e.preventDefault(); // this will stop the page moving when the arrow is pressed

      var prevRows = currentRow.prevAll('tr').not('.Header,.SubHeader,.Total'),  // use prevAll to get all preceding rows and then filter out ones with the classes,
          prevRow;
      
      if (prevRows.length) {
        // test if there is a matching row and then highlight it
        prevRow = prevRows.eq(0);
      } else {
        // no matching so start from the end 
        prevRow = currentRow.nextAll('tr').not('.Header,.SubHeader,.Total').last(); 
      }
      
      highlight(prevRow); // no need to figure out the index.  but if you want you would do rows.index(prevRow); - gets the index with regards to all rows
      break;

    case 40:
      e.preventDefault(); // this will stop the page moving when the arrow is pressed
      var nextRows = currentRow.nextAll('tr').not('.Header,.SubHeader,.Total'),  // same as above but next
          nextRow; 
      
      if (nextRows.length) {
        nextRow = nextRows.eq(0);
      } else {
        nextRow = currentRow.prevAll('tr').not('.Header,.SubHeader,.Total').last();  
        // no matching so start from the beginning 
      }
      
      highlight(nextRow);
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

.Header,
.SubHeader,
.Total {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data" class="DataList" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <thead>               <!-- put header into a thead so it's not included in highlighting -->
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Header">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SubHeader">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Total">
      <td>6</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With `closest` in your original answer - it is traversing through the ancestors (parents) rather than across the siblings

Comment: could it be possible to have it jump to the first (possible) line when reaching the last possible row? this looks really promising

Comment: @Dunnow see edit.  I have also stopped the page from scrolling when the arrow is pressed

Comment: <3 this seems to be exactly what expeted, thanks so much

Comment: I just thought though, you may want to move the `e.preventDefault()` into each of the case statements (otherwise it will prevent the default action for all keydowns!)

Answer (score 0):

1. change mistypo of hightlight
2. simple pre & next selector
3. if pre & next tr not found, use the first/last normal tr as the next highlight target

```js
var row = $('.DataList tbody tr.highlight');
    
   function highlight(tableIndex) {
    $('.DataList tbody tr').removeClass('highlight');
    $('.DataList tbody tr:eq('+tableIndex+')').addClass('highlight'); 
   }

   $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var currentRow = $('.DataList tbody tr.highlight');
        var normalRowSelector = 'tr:not(.Header,.SubHeader,.Total,.highlight)';
        var nextHltIndex = -1;
    switch(e.which) {
     case 38:
      nextHltIndex = currentRow.prev(normalRowSelector).index();
            if(nextHltIndex == -1){
             nextHltIndex = $(normalRowSelector).filter(":last").index();
            }
     break;
     case 40:
      nextHltIndex = currentRow.next(normalRowSelector).index();
            if(nextHltIndex == -1){
             nextHltIndex = $(normalRowSelector).filter(":first").index();
            }
     break;
    }
        highlight(nextHltIndex);
    });
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
  
.Header, .SubHeader, .Total  {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data" class="DataList" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
 <tbody>
        <tr class="Header">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            <th>header3</th>
            <th>header4</th>
            <th>header5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Header">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="SubHeader">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Total">
            <td>6</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rucjr5cm/3/)

Comment: it's not returning up to the #1 row it's works just fine going down

Answer (score 0):

I have updated jsfiddle. Can you please look into updated one

[`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/rucjr5cm/5/)

I hope you want this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rucjr5cm/6/)

I have updated the jsfiddle that you provide and the new approach seems to work just fine.

Use `not()` to prevent adding the class `highlight` to any `tr` that has the `attribute` of `class`

One more thing is your first `tr` that contains all the `th` should be included in the `thead` section before `tbody` but i have not changed it for you please do it your self

Comment: This is the one that works best to far, the issue is that I provided a simplified table structure, I want to specifically avoid .Header, .SubHeader, .Total this classes, but the rows might still have other classes. With this approach it would not work, is it possible to get a different logic to skip those pricise styles? I should also point that the table is not a fixed number of rows and it can be possible that 0 index is one of those classes I want to avoid

Comment: I did not know you want to avoid those classes, i though all you want is to avoid the grey ones. Anyway @Pete already done that for you so i guess i don't have to edit mine. :D

Comment: yep, thank you anyway, you guys were really fast didn't expect so much feedback so soon

Answer (score 0):

Id is strongly selector instead of class.

Try this

```
$('#data tr.highlight');
```